# change from file to assets does not show thumbnails

Tags: assets

I imported a lot of pictures via datagrab to a file field.
this all worked as expected. the thumbs of the file is displayed etc.

then I changed the file field to an asset field. with the same upload directories. 
now the thumbs are not showing!

If I upload another image, then suddently both thumbnails are displayed...

how could I display the thumbs directely?

could I downgrade to assets 1 somehow?

cheers
stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stefan,

Can you go to Modules > Assets and in the upper right click "Update Indexes" - then check all of those boxes and update those?

That should fix this up, if I am understanding correctly.  You can then go visit and make sure the thumbnails show up appropriately.

There is no downgrade to Assets 1 unless you have a backup of files and database and roll those back.

Comment: I did this, but the thumbs didn't show up!

Comment: Try updating to Assets 2.0.3 (just released). It fixes several bugs, one of which may have been responsible for this.

Comment: I'll do this tomorrow and will let you know! thanks

Comment: Hi brandon! the assets 2.0.3. update corrected this issue. I did run module update first, then I updated indexes and then I've changed the field type from "file" to "assets". Worked like a charm!

Comment: Woot! Thanks for the update, outline4!